# "Non-homotopic" change of variables in integral

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold endowed with a closed $2$-form $\omega$ and let $L$ be a submanifold of $X$ such that $\omega|_L = 0$. Consider a smooth map $u \colon S^1 \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $u(t,0) \in L$, $u(t,1) \in L$ for any $t$ (so that $u$ is a "cylinder glued to $L$"):

$\hspace{11em}$[image]

I consider the integral $$
\int_{S^1 \times [0,1]} u^* \omega.
$$

Suppose that the path $u(0,\cdot)$ can be homotopied to a point in $L$. Then $u$ can be homotopied to a map $\tilde u$ such that $\tilde u(0,\cdot)$ is constant:

$\hspace{5em}$[image]

Then it follows from Stokes formula and from $\omega|_L = 0$ that 
$$
  \int_{S^1 \times [0,1]} u^* \omega = \int_{S^1 \times [0,1]} \tilde u^* \omega.
$$

Now I draw a schematic picture of $\tilde u(S^1 \times [0,1])$ and it looks the image of a map $v \colon D^2 \to X$, $v|_{\partial D^2} \in L$, where $v$ maps two points on $\partial D$ to the same point in $L$ (here $D^2 = \{ z \in \mathbb C, \; |z| \leq 1\}$) so that I expect
$$
   \int_{S^1 \times [0,1]} \tilde u^*\omega = \int_{D^2} v^* \omega.
$$
Formally, $\tilde u$ and $v$ are hot homotopy equivalent since they are defined on different spaces. Could you help me to justify this "change of variables" formula?